# How to Maintain Stability of Matlab 2016a Graphics in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, matlab

Situation: Matlab does not quit but stays *busy* in normal quit in Ubuntu 16.04; only option is to kill Matlab
Matlab service have not managed to find the reason for the problem. I cannot reproduce it with Macbook Air 2013-mid nor my PCs. I can produce it with both packages `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and `modesetting`. 
Fig. 0 Matlab does not quit normally in the hardware of 16.04

[image]

Answer from the support

> There is a bug where the splash screen will persist after MATLAB has
>   started, and after it has been closed.
>
> As a temporary workaround, you can disable the splash screen by
>   specifying the “nosplash” option in the terminal: $ matlab -nosplash

I cannot maintain Matlab stable with `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and/or `modesetting`, with the commands proposed by the Matlab service.

### With `modesetting`

I do `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel` which puts `modesetting` package active.

Fig. 1 `matlab -nosplash` without movement, Fig. 2 Same but with movement and attempt to close by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image]
[image]

Another to start Matlab without the failure with the `opengl` package

```
matlab -softwareopengl
```

Fig. 2 Variety of artifacts with `matlab -softwareopengl` when `modesetting` and having little movement, Fig. 3 Same but without movements

[image] 
[image]

I asked about them the release date of the bug fix. 
They do not want to give it. This bug has been now in Matlab at least two years. I am moving my computation little by little to Mathematica and Python/..., because there are many other similar issues in Matlab.

### Current situation

No stable temporary solution for the issue. 
Working with the tech support to find some system setting, for sufficient stability.

- They propose to update to Matlab 2016b and repeat the tests there too.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Matlab: 2016a
Matlab service request: 02136797
Graphic packages: `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, `modesetting`
Ubuntu: 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 is not supported OS by Matlab. I cannot get Matlab 2016a and Matlab 2016b pre-release stable sufficiently in Ubuntu. See the list [here](http://se.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html?sec=linux&requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) about supported platforms where Debian 8.x and Ubuntu 14.04 is but not Ubuntu 16.04. 
You can try the third-party package `sudo apt-get install matlab-support` where I did not want their old `gcc` libraries. My output is failure so the bug keeps going.

My decision is to install Debian 8.x in this laptop, next to Ubuntu. 
I received an email from the support, and they confirm that Matlab 2016b will support 16.04 LTS. Its release will be some day in the next month.